# Does the IRS require a phone number to file taxes?

Tags: taxes, irs

I'm filing taxes through H&R Block, and they claim that the IRS requires my phone number. I don't believe this to be true, since the IRS always contacts you via mail. Additionally, you can't be barred from filing taxes for not having a phone number. Is this just H&R block's roundabout way to get your phone number? Or does the IRS truly **require** your number to file?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Form 1040 Instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf) indicate that phone number is optional:

> **Phone Number and Email Address**
> You have the option of entering your
> phone number and email address in the spaces provided. There will
> be no effect on the processing of your return if you choose not to
> enter this information. Note that the IRS initiates most contacts
> through regular mail delivered by the United States Postal Service.

The e-file Signature Authorization form ([Form 8879](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8879.pdf)) doesn't have a phone number space.

I'm not seeing anything that indicates the IRS requires a phone number to file taxes, it's not true that they never call, just that they do not typically call. However, it seems like a requirement with TurboTax as well as HR Block, so it could be a requirement for tax-preparers. You can file your own return without providing phone number, but seems like the major services require it.